# Installerv otb 6.6.1 under QGIS 2.18.24 in Windows 7

Tags: qgis-2, windows-7, otb-applications

I had installed QGIS 2.18.24 on OSGeo4W, then the OTB stand-alone binary file. In QGIS, I manually entered the directory of OTB Applications folder

```
C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\OTB-6.6.1-win32\lib\otb\applications)
```

and command line folder

```
C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18.24\apps\OTB-6.6.1-win32\bin
```

and I checked the `Enable` button.

But nothing happens when I close the Processing window and no OTB menu appears in the Processing toolbox.

How can I solve this problem?